# Ubuntu 14.04.1 no audio, Dummy output , model lenovo z570 codec Realtek ALC272

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio

```
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec 

output:

   Codec: Realtek ALC272
   Codec: Intel CougarPoint HDMI

 laptop Model: Lenovo z570

  "HD-Audio-Models.txt" contains

  ALC662/663/272
  ==============
  asus-mode1    ASUS
  asus-mode2    ASUS
  asus-mode3    ASUS
  asus-mode4    ASUS
  asus-mode5    ASUS
  asus-mode6    ASUS
  asus-mode7    ASUS
  asus-mode8    ASUS
```

I tried all nothing worked, also "options snd-hda-intel model=auto" didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the bug, this happens after a hard shutdown.

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1264213 

fixed it. now sound works properly. but wasted a lot of time doing nonsense for days.

added this line to the file "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf"

      "options snd-hda-intel model=ideapad"  and then

       "sudo alsa force-reload"   and then

       reboot

for more info visit this thread => http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1316634 


edit: 

    the above solution is not a permanent solution.
    Installing NVidia driver fixed the problem. This looks ridiculous but works.
```